# ¿Como puedo hacer para verificar que un Integer ingresado, si es null retorne false?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2, booleano

**Hola buenas, necesito ayuda como puedo lograr lo escrito anterioremente ademas me marca un error de nullpointer en la fila 3 debo llegar a unos resultados pero tengo varios errores y no lo logro**

```
public Boolean numeroCapicua(Integer num) {
    Boolean respuesta = true;
    if (num.equals(123454321) || num.equals(-123454321) || num.equals(2) || num.equals(0)||(num.equals(123))) {
    } else if (num.equals(null) || (num.equals(231)) || (num.equals(MAX_VALUE))) {
    respuesta = false;
    }
    return respuesta;
}
```

**Deberia llegar a estos resultados pero hay unos errores que no logro completar desde ya agradezco su ayuda y que guien un poco en que si lo estoy haciendo bien, por cierto al numero Integer lo pido desde main mediante numerocapicua(leer.nextInt())**
**RESULTADOS**

```
 public void numeroPalindromoTest() {
    assertEquals(true, pr.numeroCapicua(123454321));
    assertEquals(true, pr.numeroCapicua(-123454321));
    assertEquals(true, pr.numeroCapicua(2));
    assertEquals(true, pr.numeroCapicua(0));
    assertEquals(false, pr.numeroCapicua(null));
    assertEquals(false, pr.numeroCapicua(231));
    assertEquals(true, pr.numeroCapicua(123));
    assertEquals(false, pr.numeroCapicua(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
}
```

**EDIT**

```
   public Boolean numeroCapicua(Integer num) {
    Boolean respuesta = true;
    if (num.equals(123454321) || num.equals(-123454321) || num.equals(2) || num.equals(0) || (num.equals(123))) {
        respuesta = true;
    }
    if ((num <= 0 || num > 0) || (num.equals(231)) || (num.equals(Integer.MAX_VALUE))) {
        respuesta = false;
    }
    return respuesta;
}
```

**ASI ME QUEDO **
**LOS UNICOS ERRORES QUE ME MARCA SON QUE SOLO ES QUE AHORA A 123454321 ME LO TOMA COMO FALSE PERO SUPONGO QUE TRATARE DE ARREGLARLO**
**epexted:true but was:false-------**
**junit.framework.assertionfailederror**

Comment: En java no puedes pasar un int como null, por eso se crea el NullPointerException , y en segundo lugar , porque pasar un parametro como null?

Comment: anteriormente había echo if(num==null) y si era igual que me retorne false pero tampoco me funciono como podría hacerlo ? esta es una de las preguntas que me pide el ejercicio ---Contemplar que el numero que llega puede ser null, si es así debe devolver false.---

Comment: Has intentado en vez de "if(num == null)" , "if(num <= 0 || num >0)" esto verificara si es un numero.

Comment: ahi logre arreglarlo ya no me marca el cartel rojo de error sino el amarillo pero aun asi me marca algunos errores todavia pero parece que me funciono

Comment: Podría servirte usar [Objects.requireNonNull](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T))

Comment: MAX_VALUE debe estar antecedido por Integer.MAX_VALUE , creo que eso deberia arrojarte un error de la forma que lo tienes.

Comment: ahi comente un edit arriba de como me quedo y los errores te agradezco mucho tu ayuda porque hace pocoo comenze a cursar programacion y cuesta

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que estás enfocando mal el ejercicio que te han mandado.

El [Desarrollo Guiado por Pruebas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desarrollo_guiado_por_pruebas), del inglés TDD (Test-Driven Developement), es una estrategia avanzada de programación que podemos resumir en que primero se escriben los test y luego se hace la implementación que valide esos test. Pero nunca hay que dejar de lado que tu código tiene que cumplir unos requisitos, NO solo validar los test. Cualquier otro programador de tu equipo puede incluir otros nuevos casos de prueba en ese test y la gente del equipo de test NO va a emplear esos mismos casos de prueba, pueden emplear cualquier Integer, incluyendo null.

Si te han encargado implementar un método que determine si un Integer es capicua o no, eso es lo que tienes que implementar y no un método que pase ese test concreto.
Tu método tiene que ser **válido para cualquier Integer, incluyendo el valor null**, no solo para el pequeño conjunto de Integers indicado en el test.

Si empleamos tu última implementación, quitándole esto `(num <= 0 || num > 0)` que **no sirve para nada porque todos los enteros lo cumplen** (salvo el valor especial `null`).

```
public Boolean numeroCapicua(Integer num) {
    Boolean respuesta = true;
    if (num.equals(123454321) || num.equals(-123454321) 
     || num.equals(2) || num.equals(0) || (num.equals(123))) {
        respuesta = true;
    }

    if ((num.equals(231)) || (num.equals(Integer.MAX_VALUE))) {
        respuesta = false;
    }

    return respuesta;
}
```

Y modificamos ligeramente el test para incluir el número 18, que NO es capicua

```
public void numeroPalindromoTest() {
    assertEquals(true, pr.numeroCapicua(123454321));
    assertEquals(true, pr.numeroCapicua(-123454321));
    assertEquals(true, pr.numeroCapicua(2));
    assertEquals(true, pr.numeroCapicua(0));
    // assertEquals(false, pr.numeroCapicua(null));
    assertEquals(false, pr.numeroCapicua(231));
    assertEquals(true, pr.numeroCapicua(123));
    assertEquals(false, pr.numeroCapicua(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    assertEquals(false, pr.numeroCapicua(18));
}
```

El test falla porque has puesto que por defecto el método devuelva true.

No te voy a implementar el método numeroCapicua porque este sitio web no está enfocado en resolver ejercicios pero puedo darte un par de pinceladas.

Por un lado, por los test interpreto que en los números negativos se descarta el signo - y también pueden ser capicúas. Una forma fácil de quitar el símbolo es emplear el valor absoluto del número que te pasen.

Por otro lado, para determinar si un número es capicúa o no tienes que ver si su primera cifra coincide con la última y luego comprobar si lo que queda en medio es capicúa o no. Si transformas el valor absoluto del entero en una cadena de caracteres, un String, esto te permitirá acceder fácilmente al primer carácter y al último y compararlos y luego aplicar recursivamente el método sobre la subcadena restante de quitar esos dos caracteres.

Por último dado que la mayoría de números no son capicúas, el valor por defecto que deberías asignar a respuesta debería ser false.

Bonus: si tienes esta estructura en un método

```
public boolean isLoQueSea() {
    boolean res = false;

    if (cond1 || cond2) {
       res = true;
    } else if (cond3 || cond4) {
       res = true;
    }   

    return res; 
}
```

Lo de arriba es equivalente a

```
public boolean isLoQueSea() {
    return (cond1 || cond2 || cond3 || cond4);
}
```

Te puede parecer una tontería pero cuando tienes cientos o miles de líneas de código que revisar, se agradecen bastante estas simplificaciones.

Bonus II: No tienes que creer ciegamente en nada de lo que te digan aquí ni en ningún otro foro, tienes que comprobar por ti mismo la veracidad de lo expuesto, empleando el sentido común, las pruebas empíricas y contrastando con otras fuentes, como la documentación oficial de Oracle.

Me refiero a afirmaciones como *en java no puedes darle valor null a un Integer* (lo cual es totalmente falso) o la condición que te he señalado (totalmente superflua al ser siempre true), por ejemplo. Esto vale también para todo lo que yo haya indicado arriba. Es responsabilidad tuya verificar todo lo expuesto.

Answer (score -1):

```
//aqui cambie el tipo Integer a int
public Boolean numeroCapicua(int num) {
    Boolean respuesta = true;
    //Para comparar int usa ==
    if (num == 123454321 || num == -123454321 || num == 2 || num == 0|| num == 123) {
        respuesta = true;
    } else if ((num <= 0 || num > 0) || num == 231 || num == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        respuesta = false;
}
    return respuesta;
}
//Si usas numeroCapicua((int) 123454321); ya te devolvera true
```

Comment: mil gracias hermano, de apoco voy entendiendo solo veo un error que a int no puedo usarlo como null tiene que ser Integer y ese es mi problema hace rato :/

Comment: ahora en el test de "numeropalidromotest" quue comparti arriba me marca como error el null :/

Comment: Como te dije anteriormente , en java no puedes darle valor null a un Integer por eso es que te saltan esos errores , lo primero que deberias revisar el porque pasarias null en ese metodo y si es necesario.

Comment: "En java no puedes darle valor null a un Integer" Esta afirmación es falsa. Cuando te dan el enunciado de un ejercicio o el acuerdo de interfaz con terceros con la signatura de un método NO puedes cambiarlo a tu libre albedrio y donde pone Integer poner int.